# Is it possible to see live the connected devices with the router in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to see live the connected devices with the router on flutter. That means I need the IP-address and the MAC-ADDRESS. Is that possible with flutter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all detail of your connected devices even device name, mac address,... with this package: https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_info_plugin#-readme-tab-